# Ubuntu on Aspire 3 A314-31 won't boot after update

Tags: grub2, updates, password, bios, acer

I have an Acer Aspire 3 A314-31 that was running perfect with ubuntu. After I made an update (I always let do all the updates without checkin what it is), my laptop won't boot ubuntu. It goes straight to windows. I suposed that was a grub problem so I tried to boot linux from an usb to fix it but it won't boot. I suposed that it was a bios configuration issue and I tried to enter it and it asks me a password (I think I can recall that it never ask me for password and/or I didn't have problems booting from an usb). Thank you for advanced.